# Can this tag be [fixed]? Or should we burninate it?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, tag-disambiguation

This is a discussion about if we should burninate this tag. It is *not* an invitation to burninate it. Anyone that attempts to ignore/suggests ignoring [the official process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324070) risks moderator action.

---

I think we should burninate the [fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fixed) tag. Here's the tag wiki and info:

> Please don't use; the more specific [css-position] or [fixed-point] tags are preferred.
>
> ---
>
> (review to be retagged [css-position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-position) or [fixed-point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fixed-point), remove otherwise)

So... I propose we burninate it. Let's look at the criteria:

1. *Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?*

   This tag is not clear. It can refer to any of the following:

   - Fixed point math (from the tag wiki)
   - Positioning elements using CSS (from the tag wiki)
   - Questions with issues that need to be *fixed*
   - Fixed time intervals
   - The [`fixed` keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21981132/whats-the-use-of-c-sharp-keyword-fixed-unsafe) in C#
2. *Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?*

   Admittedly, somewhat, but... it's still a bad tag. Some of these are, such as the `fixed` keyword. And questions about problems that the OP wants *fixed* may be on-topic.
3. *Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?*

   No
4. *Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?*

   Absolutely not. See question #1 for some examples of other uses of the tag.
5. *Is the tag causing a fairly large amount of harm?*

   Eh... it's not, like, hurting anyone (hopefully!). But, it's still a poor tag.

How should we deal with the [fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fixed) tag? Burninate it? Retag questions with it? Something else entirely?

Comment: Maybe just clean it up and merge into css-position?

Comment: The answer "No" for "Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?" doesn't look fair. According to your other description, the tag actually **adds** meaningful information: either a fixed math, or positioning in CSS, or something else. That is, burnination of the tag would require adding *some other tag(s)* for the questions. Despite of the note "A tag must fail ALL of those tests in order to be considered for burnination." in the referenced process, burnination of a tag could be performed even with passed one or more of "4 tests". So, do not force all of these tests to fail.

Comment: ... Actually, the great ambiguity (failed the 1st test) **alone** seems to be a very reason to somehow handle the tag, either by removing it or by synonymizing to some other tag.

Comment: No nuke from orbit. As per usual this opens a can of worms, if you click on that tag you get a wealth of pointlessness. I see one question tagged "css position css-position". Well now it's twice as clear!

Comment: it also relates to [*I fixed it*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXx0L.jpg), which itself is very ambiguous

Answer (score 22):

I believe it's a good candidate for going. The absolutely fatal thing is that it has many different meanings and so contributes nothing formally but confusion. Nobody would want to watch the tag. It doesn't make anything easier to find. It doesn't help search engines categorize things.

Yes, that means there needs to be a clean-up job in Aisle 6.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to give yet another burn answer for a different reason. This tag is a cognitive hazard. Its mere existence invites people to add the tag to questions with full solutions to them. We definitely don't want any tag that does that.

Partial disambiguate guidance:

Fixed point math: [fixed-point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fixed-point)

Fixed position css: [css-position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-position)

There's a large number of [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) questions using [fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fixed) for a kind of numerical analysis. I can't quite find the tag. If you find it, please edit it in here.

Fixed blocks in C#: [unsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unsafe) ; most questions will also need [memory-management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-management) (yup; that keyword goes with unsafe keyword)

A handful of questions (for example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60644406/implementing-ienumeratort-for-fixed-arrays)) want [array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/array).

Comment: Do not tag questions about fixed position CSS with [css-position] [absolute]. `absolute` is a different value for the `position` property with different rules and different behavior and we should not conflate the two. Using [css-position] alone should be sufficient for all of the values of the property.

Comment: @HereticMonkey: Fixed. Sorry, I'm bad at CSS.